# Fleck with auf vs. an, is there a more general rule?

Tags: word-usage, preposition

I noticed that it's common to use *Fleck* with *auf* rather than *an*. For example *Es gibt einen Fleck auf Ihrem Hemd.* ("There is a stain on your shirt.") My understanding is ''auf'' means "on top of" while ''an'' means "attached to", "leaning on", "hanging on/from". So it seems odd that *auf* rather than *an* would be the preferred preposition here. Is this just a random exception or is this part of a more general pattern? Apparently with *Farbe* the preferred preposition is *an*, as in *Es gibt Farbe an der Wand.* ("There is paint on the wall.") But there are exceptions with this: *Es gibt Farbe auf der Palette.* (There is paint on the palette.") I suppose it's because a palette can be held horizontally.

Comment: Note, that like in English "auf"/"on" can very well mean "on the surface of" instead of "on top of" - which is the case here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This follows straight from the progressive aspect, *sich etwas **über** das Hemd schütten*. Consequently, the stain is *upon* the chemise, so to speak, not *onto*.  (PS: this should be logical, that fluids come from above, because they generally flow down wards).

The preposition is occasionally allowable, per chance, if the stain is superficial, so you might have *Ketchup an der Backe*, but this has never been applicable with cotton wool to my knowledge. Further, we'd more likely say *im Gesicht*, not *an*, showing that it depends on the location and how it combines.

Imaginably, English has generalized this to *on* under inuence of French *en*, which I understand combines both n-prepositions, in turn under the influence of Frankish, though the severely reduced *á* might also have played a role.

Comment: So, since the stain was theoretically some fluid that dropped onto the surface, it would be *auf*. That makes some sense and seems to apply to *Spritzer*. I might expect *Grasfleck* to work differently in that case; apparently it doesn't but I don't expect 100% logical consistency. I don't think I use "upon" and I feel it's rather dated, so to me *auf* and *an* are both either *on* or *onto*.

Comment: Stains may very well be caused by non-fluids. I'd say that interpreting the shirt as carrier substance, as by guidot's answer, offers a much more natural explanation.

Comment: @Lykanion,I'm not super convinced by own answer, lol, but I did say it depends on the location and I won't *overthink*this beyond that

Answer (score 4):

I'm somehwat surprised, that DWDS does not offer a dedicated meaning for *an* as well as *auf*.

No, I don't think is has to do with the orientation of the stained surface. Neither  would I translate *auf* with *on top of* but rather prefer *upon*.

Numerous other examples exists:

- Auf dem Bildschirm...
- Auf dem Gemälde...
- Auf dem Plakat...
- Auf dem Foto...

I would mostly use *auf*, when the "carrier" is used as a reference and offers the surface exhibiting something.

Counter-examples using *am* exist, however, but I don't see a clear and easy rule here:

- Ich habe einen blauen Fleck am Schienbein.
- Am Kotflügel ist ein Kratzer.

Comment: Aam Kotflügel in sein Lack da is en Kratzer

Comment: Schienbein ist technisch ein Knochen, den kann man ja nicht sehen. Also *am* wie *in der Nähe*. Auch *am Fuß*,. . . na gut, ja, ist ein wichtiger Punkt. Vielleicht verkürzt aus *op'm*?

Comment: As I mentioned in another comment, I don't use "upon" and had to look up the difference between it and "on" in the dictionary. Maybe it's one of things that only people who learn English as a second language are taught. There does seem to be a general rule about using *auf* with images/carriers that's worth remembering. I'm not convinced it applies to *Palette* but it's certainly possible.

Comment: PS. I think it's interesting that German uses *blau* for bruises (*blauer Fleck*, *blaues Auge*) instead of "black" as in English. English has "black and blue", but neither can be taken literally.

Comment: @RDBury: "... not a trace to mark his fall, nor a stain upon the wall" is original English speech, well song ;-)

Comment: @a_donda: Yes, I'm sure there are native English speakers who use "upon", I'm just saying I'm not one of them. I'm not familiar with the song you quoted, but from the title and the tone, it's in the style of E.A. Poe, and Poe did use "upon" whenever possible. As much as I like Poe's work, by today's standards his style is very flowery and elevated; not something you'd see in modern work unless that's the effect the author is going for.

Comment: @RDBury: Phenomenal ! It was Alan Parsons Project who set into song short stories by Poe. Whatever, it just proves that these prepositions have no fixed rules and may even depend on personal use or lack thereof and there's no fixed for their use. They may be (hear, hear) idiomatic ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is as it is :-)

Just like a stain is upon but a writing on the wall.

Ein Fleck ist auf, ein Knopf an der Bluse, eine Nudel ist im Gesicht.

But I would translate "auf" not only with "on top of", that'll be more like "über". I don't think there are general equivalents either way in both languages for these prepositions/adverbs/prefixes.

Comment: Yes, prepositions are certainly tricky for learners; just when you think you've learned a specific meaning which can be translated a certain way, you discover mysterious and apparently random exceptions. I think I would usually translate *über* as either "over" or "above"; only "on" if it's a topic: *Dies ist ein Buch über Deutsch.* -- "This is a book on German."

Comment: @RDBury yeah, but "Das ist ein Buch über deutsch" as awkward German, it is an incomplete sentence. "Das ist ein Deutschbuch", "... über deutsche Grammatik/Redensarten" would make it better. And a language is not a stain, so different idioms apply.